# Networkprogramming Python UDP recvfrom doesnt work

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

```
This is the server side
import socket

UDP_IP = 'localhost'
UDP_PORT = 6000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

   if data:
    sock.sendto(data.upper(),(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT) )
    sock.sendto(UDP_IP,(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
#print "sending"
```

This is the client side
    import socket

```
UDP_IP = 'localhost'
UDP_PORT = 6000  
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP



message = raw_input("Your Message: ")
sock.sendto(message, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

data=sock.recvfrom(1024)
print "receiving"    #this line when running it does not print
localtime= time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
print("Received:",data,"at",localtime)

sock.close()
```

How to fix the code of client side to receive data from server side? because it does not print out the data that has been received.

Answer (score 1):

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM


def udp_server(host='localhost', port=3000, buffersize=4096, public=False):
    host = '0.0.0.0' if public else host
    address = (host, port)
    with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
        s.bind(address)
        while True:
            data, address = s.recvfrom(buffersize)
            print('Received:\t{} from {}'.format(data, address))



def upload_data(payload, host='localhost', port=3000):
    """Upload data to server."""

    if payload:
        try:
            s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
            s.sendto(bytearray(payload), (host, port))
        finally:
            s.close()
```

Run the server on an interpreter. Then on another one, call `upload_data(b'hello').

Note, it's good if you take advantage of the context manager provided by socket to ensure everything is closed when you're done.